# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near '>'

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to use nested IIF functions that compares the Sum of Balances for different debt levels. However, I keep getting this error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
> Incorrect syntax near '>'.

I am not sure what the incorrect syntax is. The greater than signs are underlined. I tried redoing the parenthesis and brackets. Perhaps it's something else I missed? Here is the code section that affects the error message:

```
IIF(SUM(InvoiceTotal - PaymentTotal - CreditTotal) BETWEEN 11000 AND
    SUM(InvoiceTotal - PaymentTotal - CreditTotal) > 500, 'High', NULL),
IIF(SUM(InvoiceTotal - PaymentTotal - CreditTotal) BETWEEN 500 AND
    SUM(InvoiceTotal - PaymentTotal - CreditTotal) > 200, 'Medium', Null),
```

Comment: X between 1100 and 1200 or X > 500. Between+and is a ternary expression.

Comment: `BETWEEN` takes a range (as in BETWEEN 1 AND 10). You've not used it properly. Also, BETWEEN 11000 AND SUM() > 500 clearly doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I think I finally see where you're going with this. I realized I didn't need the second SUM statement and the greater than signs since I'm already using the required BETWEEN operator.

Comment: Also beware that `BETWEEN` has a specific definition in SQL that requires that the lower bound be stated first. You can certainly write `BETWEEN 10 AND 1` but that will never match anything. `BETWEEN 1 AND 10` would be what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose that you want to get these values:

- When the sum is over 11000 you get value "High"
- When it is between 11000 and 500 you get "Medium"
- When it is between 500 and 200 you get "Low"
- When it is under 200 you get "Super low"

I do not know if those are the values you want, but I am sure you can adjust them.

This could be your code:

```
SELECT
IIF(SUM(InvoiceTotal - PaymentTotal - CreditTotal) > 11000, 'High',
IIF(SUM(InvoiceTotal - PaymentTotal - CreditTotal) > 500, 'Medium', 
IIF(SUM(InvoiceTotal - PaymentTotal - CreditTotal) > 200, 'Low', 'Super Low')))
```

Is this what you needed?

Comment: Excellent example. Just what I needed!